# Entity Framework Core. How to map two collections to one column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have following model, which I want to manage with Entity Framework Core:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsReport
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ReportText { get; set; }

    public List<Product> GoodProducts { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
    public List<Product> BadProducts { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

Here I'm creating entities:

```
using (ProductsDbContext db = new ProductsDbContext())
        {
            Product p1 = new Product
            {
                Name = "Orange",
                Price = 10
            };

            Product p2 = new Product
            {
                Name = "Lemon",
                Price = 7
            };

            Product p3 = new Product
            {
                Name = "Salt",
                Price = 1
            };

            Product p4 = new Product
            {
                Name = "Sugar",
                Price = 3
            };

            db.Products.AddRange(p1, p2, p3, p4);

            ProductsReport rep1 = new ProductsReport
            {
                Author = "Me",
                ReportText = "I can say, that some prodcuts are bad",
                BadProducts = new List<Product> { p1, p2 },
                GoodProducts = new List<Product> { p3, p4 }
            };

            db.ProductsReports.Add(rep1);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

But this creates me following Products table:

```
+----+--------+-------+------------------+--------------------+
| ID | Name   | Price | ProductsReportID | ProductsReportID1  |
+----+--------+-------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Orange |   10  | 1                | NULL               |
| 2  | Lemon  |    7  | 1                | NULL               |
| 3  | Salt   |    1  | NULL             | 1                  |
| 4  | Sugar  |    3  | NULL             | 1                  |
```

There are two colums with foreign ket to the same ProductsReport entity.

Is there any way to specify Entity Framework that it should create only single foreign key?

Comment: Add a new column with a state to your product ( Enum with Bad or Good ). Easier than you want

Comment: This is my reserve solution. But I wouldn't like to edit the structure of the model. Maybe there are some attributes or it is possible to do with ModelBuilder?

Comment: You can't do that at model level. EF does not support "logical" relationships.